# Custom LINK share URL for Facebook and G+

Tags: asp.net, facebook, google-plus

I dont know if this question is welcomed by SO or not but i am very beginner in programming.
I am sharing links from my page to facebook and google+ with following technique.

```
    http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=txtUrl.txt&t=txtTitle.text

    https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=txtUrl.txt
```

But in this way i am opening a new window where the users are getting an extra share button. But i want users to directly share a link along with the title which is respectively taken from current url and title tag.
Is it only possible if i use their API or not !

Comment: Are you saying you want your users to share to FB/G+ with a single click instead of one click to open the popup and one click to share the post?

Comment: Yes, I want user to write title on my custom input box and directly share links from my page instead of opening another window or pop-up to share

Comment: Then you def shouldn't be using the method above which by default opens a new tab. Both companies offer buttons which achieve this functionality via JS/API call. The only time you should use the above code is when incorporating share buttons in an HTML email or other non-javascript environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only official way to share to Google+ is using the [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/). Users can add a comment when they share but the title is automatically pulled from the `<title/>` attribute in the pages HTML.

Facebook has the [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) that works the same as the +1 button. Users will have an options to add a comment to the like but the link title is automatically pulled from the page's HTML.

Facebook also supports a [post method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) through their API. You can achieve a one click share using this but users will have to authenticate and allow your app access. The title will still automatically populate from the page however.